# JSON to HTML table with PHP

Tags: php, json

How can I display the JSON below in a HTML table with PHP/HTML? I saw some other examples so far but I cant find out how I could use them with my JSON because there is the JSONArray and record section infront of the data.

```
{"JSONArray":{"record":[{"joined":1396627177212,"name":"kate","rank":"MEMBER","id":"424a0dc79bbb49971a599c80b9d8","dailyCoins-11-9-2015":200},{"joined":1396629936746,"name":"verna","rank":"MEMBER","id":"042896991242f9889d3276f83861","dailyCoins-11-9-2015":590},{"joined":1397048326142,"name":"lucy","rank":"MEMBER","id":"f36ca59409a60a81b110cf6ac714"},{"joined":1411762368798,"name":"christopher","rank":"MEMBER","id":"25108a666d451a923abb19213197","dailyCoins-10-9-2015":880,"dailyCoins-11-9-2015":475},{"id":"b5b733529e4a92ba8f7e2b481290","rank":"MEMBER","joined":1440161306320},{"id":"d2ff8bb9817440aae5c140b81955","rank":"MEMBER","joined":1440611487342},{"id":"e7ede489e4078798fd2c69ee8be6","rank":"MEMBER","joined":1442934056516,"dailyCoins-11-9-2015":460},{"id":"dd9ecd7a5c0f40c265dc6487261c","rank":"MEMBER","joined":1443546076415,"dailyCoins-10-9-2015":520,"dailyCoins-11-9-2015":200},{"id":"aafe27c0544fa394da721aebb220","rank":"MEMBER","joined":1443546124859},{"id":"270bea34095147863c11c7a62ea3","rank":"MEMBER","joined":1443546454759,"dailyCoins-10-9-2015":100},{"id":"a97f1d0ed0a44a928231c6fd9c7c","rank":"MEMBER","joined":1443546461462,"dailyCoins-10-9-2015":400,"dailyCoins-11-9-2015":220},{"id":"4ec268a2d18445a9399a3706b416","rank":"MEMBER","joined":1443546587154,"dailyCoins-11-9-2015":400},{"id":"26114b8edd184483895447d016f5","rank":"MEMBER","joined":1443546851165,"dailyCoins-10-9-2015":50,"dailyCoins-11-9-2015":980},{"id":"cca06c6cfa4cb7b3feb491b2a33c","rank":"MEMBER","joined":1443547050965},{"id":"cba38c69d199448d29bc315f850c","rank":"MEMBER","joined":1443547055696},{"id":"aad9060b693e4dc431687f91f404","rank":"MEMBER","joined":1443547070245,"dailyCoins-10-9-2015":80},{"id":"38876b0a546d44b8bf4f1d224a64","rank":"MEMBER","joined":1443547325591,"dailyCoins-11-9-2015":100},{"id":"6a35e9dfc0e842af93e8200e4d5a","rank":"MEMBER","joined":1443548006094},{"id":"13e287923dcb489c398512066348","rank":"MEMBER","joined":1443548827377},{"id":"a63d75a7db4674h6f2d81efedb1e6","rank":"MEMBER","joined":1443548952273,"dailyCoins-10-9-2015":255},{"id":"1e036c43824736b7a43636652f53","rank":"MEMBER","joined":1443549877348,"dailyCoins-10-9-2015":720,"dailyCoins-11-9-2015":380},{"id":"23a331cfacd844903084c075a04e","rank":"MEMBER","joined":1443549911657,"dailyCoins-10-9-2015":480},{"id":"229638c216a34acd97730b661615","rank":"MEMBER","joined":1443550075437},{"id":"5fa71907e8814cbdcdf730c116b5","rank":"MEMBER","joined":1443550083753,"dailyCoins-10-9-2015":60},{"id":"cbaf32d0c3ab4e9d690655df2ab2","rank":"MEMBER","joined":1443552053749,"dailyCoins-10-9-2015":290},{"id":"684d053c532b4095f100695e86e1","rank":"MEMBER","joined":1443552064766,"dailyCoins-10-9-2015":100,"dailyCoins-11-9-2015":30},{"id":"c9b75606f7e84e91998bc8a905d1","rank":"MEMBER","joined":1443553369085},{"id":"301bfd2965424562d8bc4e633dd3","rank":"MEMBER","joined":1443553480028,"dailyCoins-10-9-2015":130},{"id":"0cf8af3ff14c0984a56fe03562ba","rank":"MEMBER","joined":1443553490690},{"id":"d3e29112b0863cb0c5087d136667","rank":"MEMBER","joined":1443553994063},{"id":"6c1d648ea482429babd18cd151f4","rank":"MEMBER","joined":1443628880615,"dailyCoins-10-9-2015":190,"dailyCoins-11-9-2015":25},{"id":"a5c38d3f77af4678ej40cc069a8ec","rank":"MEMBER","joined":1443811816283,"dailyCoins-10-9-2015":230,"dailyCoins-11-9-2015":25},{"id":"16ab1b04504a33bd504fc72d580c","rank":"MEMBER","joined":1443816233615,"dailyCoins-10-9-2015":125,"dailyCoins-11-9-2015":395},{"id":"1f08be5b8a4ea92d91f24f209ed4","rank":"MEMBER","joined":1444211861989,"dailyCoins-10-9-2015":560,"dailyCoins-11-9-2015":120},{"id":"27adaa178844cbfc02770a443cbf","rank":"MEMBER","joined":1444389831435,"dailyCoins-10-9-2015":200},{"id":"53422792b14b600f46b3a4455930","rank":"MEMBER","joined":1444396739744,"dailyCoins-10-9-2015":670,"dailyCoins-11-9-2015":530},{"id":"3caa1a6c889a4d6e93cba50577a8","rank":"MEMBER","joined":1444397559705,"dailyCoins-10-9-2015":720,"dailyCoins-11-9-2015":820},{"id":"a4de5bb8904b5f474ba64e9760f1","rank":"MEMBER","joined":1444397625609,"dailyCoins-11-9-2015":570},{"id":"be99524ef644ec57d9d46419073f","rank":"MEMBER","joined":1444397712148,"dailyCoins-10-9-2015":780,"dailyCoins-11-9-2015":980},{"id":"9f9a8a5d934024b3e87f7a806bc8","rank":"MEMBER","joined":1444397735181,"dailyCoins-11-9-2015":230},{"id":"86f02fc1ccdee8b8e4e8a960be7d","rank":"MEMBER","joined":1444398374370},{"id":"a738f19606a44a54974b9bbabc4b","rank":"MEMBER","joined":1444398790078,"dailyCoins-10-9-2015":355,"dailyCoins-11-9-2015":160}],"extra":[],"timestamp":1444598000},"api":{}}
```

Comment: use json_decode($array) and loop the array.

Comment: Your json isn't valid, copy + paste it at http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Doesnt matter, its only an example JSON, the real JSON is valid. Its just about The JSONs structure. Could you tell me how the loop would look like with this JSON structure?

Comment: Post a valid json and I can help you..

Comment: Your json isn't valid, please provide us with a full working json.

Comment: The JSON up there should be valid now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code you want:

```
$json = '{"users":[{ "user": "Carlos", "age": 30, "country": "Spain" }, { "user": "John", "age": 25, "country": "United States" }, { "user": "Mike", "age": 28, "country": "Canada" }]}';
$arr = json_decode($json, true);

echo "<table><tr><th>user</th><th>age</th><th>country</th></tr>";

foreach($arr['users'] as $item){    
    echo "<tr><td>".$item['user']."</td><td>".$item['age']."</td><td>".$item['country']."</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

Just convert the json to array and then use a foreach and access each item property.

Comment: Thanks but how do I use this for my code? My records array that contains all the data is in another array, the JSONArray array. My code would look like this:

$arr = json_decode($json, true);
echo "<table><tr><th>joined</th><th>name</th><th>rank</th></tr>";
foreach($arr['record'] as $item){    
    echo "<tr><td>".$item['joined']."</td><td>".$item['name']."</td><td>".$item['rank']."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

but Im just getting this error:
Undefined index: record in file.php on line 85

I think this is because the record array is not in the main index.

Comment: Figured it out now, this was the solution: foreach($arr[JSONArray][record] as $key => $item){
  print "<tr><td>" . $key . "</td><td>" . $item['rank'] . "</td><td>" . $item['name'] . "</td></tr>";
}