# Convert an JSON table to an PDF with mPDF

Tags: php, json, mpdf

I'm trying to convert a JSON file to a PDF via mPDF, but my problem with that is that the JSON table is not displayed in the HTML after running the php. Only one empty PDF page is displayed.

EDIT:
I Updated the code, so it works almost. The code create the table but it don't shows all of the JSON Data.

New PHP

```
ob_start();
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$json_decoded= json_decode($json);

foreach ($json_decoded as $result) {
$html = '
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
      <title>Convert JSON Data to HTML Table</title>
      <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <meta  charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body >
      <table>
          <tr>
              <th>driverno</th>
              <th>name</th>
              <th>objectno</th>
              <th>tagId</th>
              <th>lastScanDate</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>'.$result->driverno.'</td>
            <td>'.$result->name.'</td>
            <td>'.$result->objectno.'</td>
            <td>'.$result->tagID.'</td>
            <td>'.$result->lastScanDate.'</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>'.$result->driverno.'</td>
            <td>'.$result->name.'</td>
            <td>'.$result->objectno.'</td>
            <td>'.$result->tagID.'</td>
            <td>'.$result->lastScanDate.'</td>
          </tr>
      </table>
  </body>


  </html>

';

}

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output("demo.pdf", 'F');
$mpdf->Output();
?>
```

JSON

```
 {
  "driverno":1,
  "name":"Aragorn",
  "objectno":1,
  "tagId":1,
  "lastScanDate":"yesterday"   
 },
 {
  "driverno":2,
  "name":"Legolas",
  "objectno":2,
  "tagId":2,
  "lastScanDate":"today"  
 },
 {
  "driverno":3,
  "name":"Gimmli",
  "objectno":3,
  "tagId":3,
  "lastScanDate":"today"

 },
 {
  "driverno":4,
  "name":"Gandalf",
  "objectno":4,
  "tagId":4,
  "lastScanDate":"today" 
 }
```

I get the last data of the JSON file without the tagID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mPDF does not support Javascript to this extent.

You have to parse the JSON directly in PHP with `$table = json_decode($json, true)` and then loop over it `foreach ($json as $row)` and build HTML table markup by yourself.

Be careful not to echo the code, but to build it as a string in a variable ([see this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53130693/generate-an-mpdf-to-pdf-with-html-and-php/53328632#53328632)).

Pass the string with table HTML to mPDF with `$mpdf->WriteHtml()` then.

Comment: I did it, but I don't get the Data from the JSON in the HTML table.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: It almost works, but the table only appears with the last data of the JSON. I do not quite understand that with output buffering.

Comment: Note the case of keys. `$result->tagID` is not the same as `$result->tagId`

Comment: BTW, by removing your original code, you've just made your question duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33069955/json-to-html-table-with-php.

Comment: Thank you very much, I finished it.